# How to replace NaN values with values from another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'car': ['toyota', 'toyota', 'ford', 'ford'],
 'doors': [nan, 2.0, nan, 4.0],
 'seats': [2.0, nan, 4.0, nan]})
```

that looks like this:

| car | doors | seats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| toyota | NaN | 2 |
| toyota | 2 | NaN |
| ford | NaN | 4 |
| ford | 4 | NaN |

I want to replace NaN with values from rows that match a value from a specific column (i.e car)

I want this:

| car | doors | seats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| toyota | 2 | 2 |
| ford | 4 | 4 |

Comment: What happened to rows? There are 4 rows to begin with but only 2 row in the output. What are the rules for that?

Comment: Also, what if there are 3 rows for toyota? How would it behave then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `groupby_first` method. `first` method skips `NaN` values by default.

```
out = df.groupby('car', as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
      car  doors  seats
0    ford    4.0    4.0
1  toyota    2.0    2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Your Dataframe name is Cars_df, grouping and taking maximum value should work, like below

```
   Cars_df.groupby(['car'])['door','seat'].max().reset_index()
```